# How do I change mysql $PATH on mac OSX?

Tags: mysql, macos, command-line, terminal, path

After updating `.bash_profile` , I'm getting the below path on terminal

```
Fahads-MacBook-Pro:~ jim$ cat .bash__profile
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Fahads-MacBook-Pro:~ jim$ which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

May be for this reason `service mysql stop` command is also not working! I want to make the $PATH to `/usr/local/mysql/bin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First shutdown mysql

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p shutdown
```

Then, launch mysqld by hand

```
mysqld --defaults-file=...
```

or if MySQL is running with all defaults and you are just changing datadir, do this

```
mysqld --datadir=/path/to/mysql/data
```

Here is a StackOverflow question (MySQL 'my.cnf' location?) with multiple suggestions on where my.cnf might be for Mac OS when installed .

Comment: Actually I wanted to reset mysql password. As I don't know the current password so I've used safe mode. But It doesn't allow mysql `ALTER` command in safe mode. Here's the screenshot. http://prntscr.com/c4oqbp . Please have a look.